# in "Beyond Compare" is it possible to highlight the difference between a space and non breaking space (char 32 vs char 160)?

Tags: beyondcompare

I can't make Beyond compare highlight differences between spaces and non breaking spaces.
[image]

The Ampersand is showing in red on the left but the NBSP are not showing in red making it look like the ampersand is different.
Is there a way to make the NBSP show in red in the left hand tab?
Thanks

Comment: It does not seem possible based on this recent article in the Scooter Software forum.    ....   https://forum.scootersoftware.com/forum/beyond-compare-3-discussion/text-compare-2-way/88861-ignore-non-breaking-space-vs-normal-space   .....  I have Beyond Compare here and cannot see how to do this.

Comment: Try an alternative, such as free WinMerge, https://winmerge.org/?lang=en